# R replace numeric values in nested lists with values from a vector

Tags: r, list, replace

I have a dataset like the one as follows, that I got using the `which` function before.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(123, 124, 125, 126, 127))

data <- data %>% mutate(a = list(c(11:12), c(11,12,15), integer(0), c(1,2,3), 4),
                        b = list(c(16,18), c(5,6,7), c(8,9,10), 14, 1))
```

I need to replace the numberic values in a and b with the coorresponding vavlues in from `labels`:

```
labels <- c("apple", "orange", "pear", "grapes", "lemon", "strawberry",
            "watermelon", "kiwi", "pineapple", "melon", "tangerine", "prune", 
            "cucumber", "tomato", "onion", "pepper", "garlic")
```

So 1 should become apple, 2 is orange, and if there is no number, the cell should stay empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple such columns in base R you can use `lapply` with `relist` to maintain the list structure.

```
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], function(x) relist(labels[unlist(x)], x))
data 
#   id                       a                             b
#1 123        tangerine, prune                    pepper, NA
#2 124 tangerine, prune, onion lemon, strawberry, watermelon
#3 125                                kiwi, pineapple, melon
#4 126     apple, orange, pear                        tomato
#5 127                  grapes                         apple
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(across(a:b,  ~map(.,  ~ labels[.x])))
   id                       a                             b
1 123        tangerine, prune                    pepper, NA
2 124 tangerine, prune, onion lemon, strawberry, watermelon
3 125                                kiwi, pineapple, melon
4 126     apple, orange, pear                        tomato
5 127                  grapes                         apple
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    a = list(labels[unlist(a)]),
    b = list(labels[unlist(b)])
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```